# SwiftUI .cornerRadius on Image not showing up

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently working on a SwiftUI Chat View project, and I am trying to round the corner of an image, which is loaded via a URL and converted from UIImage to Image. Any ideas why .cornerRadius(10) isn't working?

```
Image(uiImage: imageFromFirebase!)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.5, alignment: isCurrentUser ? .trailing : .leading)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(10)
```

Here is the full container – there is probably a lot of unnecessary stuff here but in case it helps:

```
struct ContentMessageView: View {
    var contentMessage: String
    var isCurrentUser: Bool
    var type: String
    var name: String
    var color: Color
    var image: UIImage?
    @State private var imageFromFirebase: UIImage?
    
    func imageLoadFromURL(){
        HTTPRequest.fetchImage(self.contentMessage) { (image) in
            if image != nil {
                imageFromFirebase = image!
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if type == "image" {
                
                if !isCurrentUser {
                    HStack{
                        Text(name).font(.caption).foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.2)).padding(.horizontal)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                HStack{
                    if isCurrentUser {
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    if imageFromFirebase != nil {
                        ZStack{
                            Image(uiImage: imageFromFirebase!)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.5, alignment: isCurrentUser ? .trailing : .leading)
//                                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .background(Color.black)
//                                    .stroke(isCurrentUser ? Color(UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1.0)) : color, lineWidth: 5))
                        }
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.05), radius: 10)
                    }
                    if !isCurrentUser {
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }.padding(.horizontal, 10)
            }
        }.onAppear(){
            self.imageLoadFromURL()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .cornerRadius(10)
                .clipped()

?

Comment: It's working for me. Can you show what code is surrounding this?

Comment: I believe the issue is that I am loading the Image from a UI Image. Does it work for you when you do that?

Comment: @SauravKumar yes, `Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "TestImage")!)` works fine.

Comment: Does this help? This is the function, called on onAppear(), which loads the remote URL:
    @State private var imageFromFirebase: UIImage?
    
    func imageLoadFromURL(){
        HTTPRequest.fetchImage(self.contentMessage) { (image) in
            if image != nil {
                imageFromFirebase = image!
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @SauravKumar I'm pretty sure the problem is the container in which the image is placed. The loading image function looks fine.

Comment: I just edited the code, it should contain the full container – do you see any issues with that?

Comment: @SauravKumar works fine... [screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/Screen%20Shot%202021-04-04%20at%202.15.30%20PM.png). We probably need some more code.

Comment: That's weird, I suppose the issue is with my `UIImage`, right? I just updated the post with the full view

Comment: @SauravKumar can you upload your image? I ran your above code and it worked fine.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YIRsgW2

Answer (score 2):

It is working fine, you did use wrong syntax and placement for code!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if let unwrappedUIImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "your image name here") {
            
            Image(uiImage: unwrappedUIImage)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
            
        }
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is then – the image shows up, it's corners just aren't rounded

Comment: have you tried my given codes? my Answer works 100%, you changed your question several time you started from question about cornerRadius and ended with debugging your project! please be more clear and more focus when you are asking for help.

Comment: Yep, that doesn't seem to work either – not sure what the problem is

Comment: The only problem is cornerRadius – not trying to debug anything

Comment: The original question was that the .cornerRadius property is not working on the image. Your answer did not work for my code.

Comment: @SauravKumar try to create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: my given code is for your original question, and yes it works indeed

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think the problem is with my specific firebase image so might have to work on that a bit haha.

Comment: your original question was trying read an Image with UIImage and also you asked why cornerRadius does not work! your issue in original question was about wrong placement of code and also force unwrapping and I answered it, now after changing your question, we can see you are into debugging your project and the question is completely changed! I know you are new in stackOverFlow, please next time be more clear and have a goal in your question, otherwise no one would pleased with multi question changing matter here!